# Connection to MySql in Docker-Container fails with Gradle

Tags: mysql, gradle, docker

I'm trying to execute commands in a MySql Docker-Container with Gradle.

This is my unsuccessful Gradle Task:

```
task hello(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn mysqlStartContainer
    executable "bash"
    args "-c", "docker exec mysql mysql -u root -p1234 -e 'select version();'"
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
 FAILED
```

There is no problem when i use the command in the console.

```
$ docker exec mysql mysql -u root -p1234 -e 'select version();'
version()
5.7.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for a few seconds after starting the container. It worked well for me.
For example, `sleep 3s` after `docker start`:

```
task mysqlStartContainer(type: Exec)  {
        executable "bash"
        args "-c", "docker start mysql && sleep 3s"
}

task hello(type: Exec)  {
        dependsOn mysqlStartContainer
        executable "bash"
        args "-c", "docker exec mysql mysql -uroot -p1234 -e 'select version()'"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have guessed that.

Now I feel a bit stupid.